# Update array of objects property value on specific condition in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this array of objects returned from server

```
{
    "Code": 200,
    "Message": "Success",
    "response": [
        {
            "UserId": null,
            "FullName": test,
            "Status": null,
            "IsActive": 1
        },
        {
            "UserId": null,
            "FullName": null,
            "Status": 'Active',
            "IsActive": 0
        }...
         ...
    ]
}
```

getting response in `List` variable

```
 this.Service.getUser(payload).subscribe(result => {
          this.List = result['response'];
 });
```

i need some way to manipulate `Status` value such as if Status is `null` the assign it `Active` value.

and again store it in `this.List` variable without using any loop.

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder how can you solve this *without using any loop*. You have to loop over `response` array.

Comment: @DecPK is there any function lwhich can solve this issue or with loop we can do without affecting performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `map` here to loop over `response` array and add `State` as `Active` if `Status === null`

```js
const apiData = {
  "Code": 200,
  "Message": "Success",
  "response": [{
      "UserId": null,
      "FullName": 'test',
      "Status": null,
      "IsActive": 1
    },
    {
      "UserId": null,
      "FullName": null,
      "Status": 'Active',
      "IsActive": 0
    }
  ]
}

const result = apiData.response.map(o => ({ ...o, Status: o.Status ?? "Active" }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your ternary is missing the "else" case. Other than that nice solution 

Comment: @PhilippMeissner This is not ternary operator instead I've used `null coalescing`

Comment: Yep, now that you made the edit that's correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the response object is an `Array`, you can just [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over it.
`{...user}` will use all of properties of the existing object. Only `Status` will be overwritten with the logic provided.

```
this.List = result['response'].map((user) => ({...user, Status: user.status === null ? 'Active' : user.status}));
```

You can not solve this issue without *some* kind of loop. That's the nature of an array.